# Вместо bootstrap-slider отображаются поля для ввода

Tags: spring, bootstrap, slider, thymeleaf

Пытаюсь реализовать пример Spring Boot + Bootstrap + Thymeleaf Slider приложения.
Вместо bootsrap-slider отображается формы для ввода. Делаю все как в  примере: https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/spring-boot-bootstrap-thymeleaf-slider. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `bootstrap-slider.css` не загружен. Убедитесь что у вас ошибка загрузки в JS Console (F12 key). Вам надо отдельно добавмть этот пакет к проекту  вот [отсуда](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) или использовать их [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider)

Comment: Спасибо заработало!